# What is the equivalent of date_select for a form_tag instead of form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't use  the f variable in a form_for so I need a date_select that is for a form_tag. How would you turn this to be used on a form_tag?

**Form_for**

```
<%= f.date_select :all_dates, :start_year => 2010, :end_year => 2012, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :use_short_month => true  %>
```

**Form_tag**

user_price = model

```
<%= date_select("user_price" , "all_dates", :start_year => 2010, :end_year => 2012, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :use_short_month => true  %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use just `date_select` without `f` if I understood you correctly, but can you show your full form code?