# Ruby on Rails timedate field for standalone form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a system which handles reservations. I am writing the UI for a user to select a start and end date which is submitted to the rooms controller and returns all available rooms for those dates. I'm struggling with

1. The actual form
2. Processing the dates in the rooms controller.

Having used `form_for` a lot, I know how datetime_select works, but using `form_tag` I can't seem to find how to implement the same thing.

Also, it looks as though using `datetime_select :year, :start_year` passes the date to the controller in 5 parameters, which is going to be messy to parse.

I wonder if I configure the form properly, the controller will know how to parse the date natively and automatically solve the second problem

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860502/what-is-the-equivalent-of-date-select-for-a-form-tag-instead-of-form-for) if I understand your question correctly then you can implement it in the same way as you would using `form_for`.